# How can I avoid CORS restriction for web audio api?

Tags: javascript, cors, web-audio-api

I trying to create some visualization for audio-stream. But I run into CORS trouble when I try get access to raw audio data with `createMediaElementSource()` function.

Is there a way to avoid this restriction and get raw audio data from stream on other origins? Perhaps using WebSockets?

Comment: Use a server-side proxy script to download and server the file. Host JS and proxy on the same server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are five ways to deal with the protections against cross-origin retrieval:

1. CORS headers -- this is ideal, but you need the cooperation of the third-party server
2. JSONP -- not appropriate for streaming content and you typically need the cooperation of the third-party server
3. Iframes and inter-window communication -- probably not appropriate for streaming content and you need the cooperation of the third-party server
4. Turning off browser protections -- you need to be running the browser in a custom mode, and you should not use that browser for anything else
5. Server-side proxy -- comparatively slow but often the only feasible option

Comment: Could you explain what CORS headers to set? I have the same problem. However, the server is mine so I can easily modify the headers. I don't know what headers to set. Thank you :)

Comment: I've already tried that. It doesn't work for what I'm doing. It's ok. My situation is probably too complicated and beyond the scope of this question. I just asked a question and revealed more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306459/cors-headers-for-accessing-a-file-on-another-domain